# How long until I can over-plant grass seed after spraying Weed b Gon

Tags: weed-control, grass

I have 5 acres of backyard that used to be farmland.  I planted grass, but I think I used the wrong kind, as it doesn't seem to be spreading.  Now ~5 years later, the yard looks decent, but the grass is fairly thin and the weeds (dandelions mostly) are starting to get heavy.  **So I sprayed Weed B Gon on it, and now want to over-plant grass seed.**

I'm not concerned about getting it perfect.  If 10% of the seed I put down comes up and starts to spread over the years, I'd consider that a win.  Every amount above that certainly welcome, but...

I just sprayed today, and it's supposed to rain in 2 days (and a few days in a row).  I was hoping I could toss down the grass seed tomorrow before rain, but I wasn't sure if that's too soon, or if it matters with this particular chemical.

**Can I over-plant grass seed a day after spraying Ortho Weed B Gon? If not, how long do I need to wait (and why)?**

Comment: I found one comment on one site that says "Plant bare spots with grass seed one week after application."  Any thoughts on it's accuracy and reasoning?

Comment: Found another that says 3 weeks.  Neither is clear as to why, but it looks like I will probably not be able to seed tomorrow.  Still interested to know for sure and what the chemical does to stop seeds from growing.  I thought it only killed the plants it was sprayed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product you used contains triclopyr as the active ingredient - this is a synthetic auxin, and its effect on seeds is either to cause them to germinate with abnormal growth, or more likely, prevent growth even if the seed does germinate. That's why the recommended gap between using it and sowing seeds is three weeks.

I'm surprised the recommended gap between treatment and seeding is only three weeks - with most chemicals used on lawns, it's six weeks.

Comment: Great, thanks!  If it rains 3-4 times in a week, does that help speed up the required wait time by washing away much of the chemical?

Comment: If they say three weeks, they're allowing for that - probably if its dry all that time, it'd be even longer, but up to you if you want to chance it

Comment: How can the chemical still be an issue after multiple rains?  Does it really stick on through a few good spring thunderstorms?

Comment: I daresay if Noah was building his Ark and that sort of rain arrived, your weedkiller would be removed earlier, but that sort of rain would preclude sowing seeds anyway. The fact is, you need to wait three weeks - if you want to believe something else, that's your right, but the fact I have given cannot be altered or it would no longer be a fact. Take a chance if you want, as I said already... you might get away with it.

Comment: I understand that you're telling me I need to wait 3 weeks, through rain or shine. My questions is not insinuating that you're wrong, I'm merely wondering HOW the chemical can still affect new grass seed after (for example), the 2+ days of thunderstorms we've been having. Saying "because I said so, and therefore it's a fact" doesn't answer the question.  While I'm inclined to believe you, I'm also very curious, as this seems counter-intuitive. I would think the large amounts of rain would wash away the chemical and then therefore not be a problem to new seeds.

Comment: Hold on a mo - its not because I said so - its because that's what the manufacturer of the product says,all I'm doing is reporting that to you.  Which therefore means I cannot change the time span recommended. Products like this will have been rigorously tested in order for them to make these kinds of recommendations, otherwise they'd have endless complaints to deal with. If you think there's been so much rain it must have disappeared by now, sow some seed, see what happens. Ultimately,, its your choice.

Comment: The product makes no mention of rain one way or the other, nor any explanation of how it could last though multiple heavy rains. You are answering with things NOT listed on the packaging, which is why I'm asking for clarification. That's all. I'm not sure why my question is seemingly being taken as an insult. It seems like a valid question.  "If the time period is regardless of rain, how does the chemical stay active/effective...etc through and beyind heavy rain?"

Comment: I'm not insulted so don't worry about that, but the manufacturers will have stated that time span for a reason - here's a  link to triclopyr's effect on germination of alfalfa seeds from which one might deduce it will have a similar effect on other seeds because it's a synthetic hormone https://www.ars.usda.gov/research/publications/publication/?seqNo115=327323

Comment: You can always contact the manufacturer of the product for clarification

Answer (score 2):

3 Weeks should be enough. I reseeded after 2 weeks and the new seeds sprouted and are doing okay. Make sure to spread starter fertilizer to boost the new growth.